# Holomorphic bounded function with zeros in $1-1/n$

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic function in unit disc, which is bounded and
>   have zeros in points $1-1/n$ for natural $n$. Then $f$ is equal to
>   zero.

Identity theorem does not help because point 1 is not inside unit disc. I suppose it follows from the fact that any holomorphic function in unit disc is either unbounded or may be extended on larger disc, but I can not prove it. Is it correct?

Comment: There are bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk that cannot be extended to a larger disk. Any bounded holomorphic function with infinitely many zeros in the disk that is $\not\equiv 0$ for example.

Comment: This is an application of the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: But limit point is 1, which is not inside of unit disc

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, I read too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Blaschke's condition: the sequence $(a_n)$ is the zero sequence of a **bounded** holomorphic function on the unit disc if and only if

$$
\sum_n (1-|a_n|) < \infty.
$$

The simplest proof is via Jensen's formula.

---

As noted, this doesn't follow from the identity theorem: there are *unbounded* holomorphic functions on the unit disc whose zero sequence is $(1-1/n)$.